# Chrome browser extension to download images from photo album webpage?

Tags: osx, chrome, download-manager

There is a site which has thumbnails and the original image appears after clicking the thumbnail: http://pages.rediff.com/jab-harry-met-sejal/2243113

Is there any Chrome extension that can download these images all together, with less effort?

Comment: you want the images, not thumbnails?

Comment: Yes that's my problem the image lies below the thumbnail u can check the example I gave

Answer (score 0):

There's a software Bulk Image Downloader at http://bulkimagedownloader.com/. I'd use this program if I really need it because I doubt if it's clean.

From their site:

> BID web browser integration is automatic for Opera and Internet
>   Explorer. FireFox and Chrome integration require extensions to be
>   installed.
>
> Save Time No more endless clicking and right clicking to "save image
>   as..."
>
> It just works No complicated configuration or project files need to be
>   set up.
>
> You're in control Preview images as thumbnails or in full size before
>   downloading. Only download those you want.
>
> Automated Downloads Queue up multiple galleries for automated
>   unattended downloading with the BID Queue Manager. Great for TGP sites
>   and web forums.
>
> One tool for all sites  Stop switching between different downloaders
>   for different web sites. BID does them all.

Comment: So I gave the site example in my op can u test if this works? I'm away from my laptop

Comment: I've used this program before. It Works well.

Comment: So that bid extension works w a pc app I own a mac 